# My question is from grammar part whether we can use two conjunction or not like this?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, coordination

Conjunctions are words which are used to link clauses which can be either dependent or independent clauses. Somewhere I have seen it's not appropriate to use two conjunctions in a single sentence. Like we have a coordinating and subordinating conjunction, so can't we use them in a single sentence? I think for some kinds of additional information we can use a conjunction even if the sentence contains *because*.

For example,

> I followed her because I was new in the city and didn't know many people there.

Is this grammatically correct or not?

Comment: Your sentence is correct *and* makes sense, *but* the rule that there's a limit as to the number of conjunctions you can use in a sentence is not correct. [I would prefer a comma after *city*, though.]

Comment: Hello, Chandan. (1) As said in the previous comment, there is no rule on the permitted number of conjunctions in a sentence (though over-lengthy sentences are always best avoided). (2) ELU expects linked, attributed references to pronouncements on (especially incorrect) grammar. (3) The sentence you ask about does not present difficulties making the question for ELU; ELL is for more basic questions.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, but note that modern grammar classifies "because" not as a conjunction but as a preposition.

Comment: Incidentally, there are in certain constructions limits to the number of _consecutive_ conjunctions.

Comment: There are *style* rules against using the same coordinating conjunction twice in one sentence, but it's not a grammar rule. It's like putting "and" between everything in a list is poor style, but not a grammar problem: "I had to do the dishes and process the laundry and walk the dog and then figure out what was for dinner."

Comment: In the ESL world, "because" is definitely described as a subordinating conjunction because what English learners need to know is that it conjoins two clauses. They don't need to be confused about this one preposition that doesn't have a noun object. Because utilitarianism

Comment: If you bothered to look, you'd see that this question was originally posted on ELU, whose users are not ESLs. And FYI, there are quite a few items that were previously regarded as conjunctions or adverbs that have been reclassified as preps. And the restriction I mentioned applies to _consecutive_ (i.e. immediately adjacent) conjunctions, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says you can only use a single conjunction in a sentence.  Your sentence is not incorrect for having both "because" and "and".

Writers use long and complex sentences with multiple conjucntions:  Here is a very long example from *Lolita*

> “My very photogenic mother died in a freak accident (picnic, lightning) when I was three, and, save for a pocket of warmth in the darkest past, nothing of her subsists within the hollows and dells of memory, over which, if you can still stand my style (I am writing under observation), the sun of my infancy had set: surely, you all know those redolent remnants of day suspended, with the midges, about some hedge in bloom or suddenly entered and traversed by the rambler, at the bottom of a hill, in the summer dusk; a furry warmth, golden midges.

You can find subordinate clauses such as  "*when* I was three" "*if* you can still stand my style"; coordinate phrases "entered *and* traversed", "My ... mother died ... and, ..., nothing of her subsists..."

Comment: Providing they're not consecutive (i.e. immediately adjacent), of course.